# Couchdb design document to search in array

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a json document like this

```
{
  "_id": "73a43a134b4169f04ddb734ef09785e9",
  "title": "US",
  "areas": 
[
{
      "text": "xyz"
}

{
      "text": "abc"
}
]

}
```

I need to search the document with areas = xyz

I have created design document like this, but not getting results. any idea ?

```
{
  "_id": "_design/areaapp",
  "filters": {
    "by_area": "function(doc, req) { for( var i=0, l=doc.areas.length; i<l; i++) { return doc.areas[i].text === req.query.area;  }}"
  }
}
```

here is my link
https://hostname/databse/_changes?filter=areaapp/by_area&area=xyz

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it sorted

```
{
  "_id": "_design/areaapp",
  "filters": {
    "by_area": "function(doc, req) {  if (doc.areas) {if(doc.areas.length > 0) {for(var idx in doc.areas) {if(doc.areas[idx].text==req.query.area) {return true; }}}}}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm. this is not the way how to query couchdb .. 
you need to write a view like

```
    {
      "_id": "_design/areaapp",
      "_views": {
        "by_area":{ 
          "map": "function(doc, req) { 
                   for( var i=0, l=doc.areas.length; i<l; i++) { 
                     emit (doc.areas[i].text,1)
                   }
                  }"
              }
         }
   }
```

this will store the btree results in couchdb.

later you can query like 
/_view/byArea?key="xyz"

then you get the id's of the docs as result.. 
or
/_view/byArea?key="xyz"&include_docs=true 
to get the docs itself as a result